# Bouncing Conversation bubble component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

If you are not logged into Stackoverflow and go to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs

You will see a bouncing conversation bubble, like this
https://prnt.sc/o06x5p

The animation is somewhat like this:
https://codepen.io/halink0803/pen/qdVXqm

and this is the code from https://codepen.io/halink0803/pen/qdVXqm
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="bounce_button">Hover Me</span>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 100%, 20%, 50%, 80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform:     translateY(0);
        transform:         translateY(0)
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        -ms-transform:     translateY(-30px);
        transform:         translateY(-30px)
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -ms-transform:     translateY(-15px);
        transform:         translateY(-15px)
    }
}
span {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: red;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  color: white;
}
span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -moz-animation-name: bounce;
}
```

I am trying to recreate this using Vanilla Javascript in Vue.js (no jQuery) and CSS3. The conversation bubble needs to be an overlay on an element of the page and:
1. something you can close by pressing 'x'
2. you can specify which element to point to
3. the direction of the arrow (and bubble) can be customized (top, bottom, left, right)

Ideally, this would be a Vue.js component, but I am new to Vue.js and not very good at Javascript in general. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: You included code but forgot to mention what problem you are having with that code.

Comment: @MatJ the code I have included is from https://codepen.io/halink0803/pen/qdVXqm I haven't written any vue.js code yet. Don't know how to start.

Comment: Still stuck on this. Thoughts appreciated.